# Comments not visible on Documentation Proposed Changes page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

When I first loaded https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/6516 I did not see any comments on the syntax section. After leaving a comment I now see there was another comment 58 mins ago:

[image: comment was hidden before]

If I reload the page, my comment is visible, but the other one is missing:

[image: missing comment]

Smells like a caching issue.

Answer (score 2):

This was a subtle bug.  That proposed change was retracted and resubmitted in between the comments, meaning that the last comment ended up in the wrong place.

We now check for this case, and report that a page is out of date should it happen.

Comment: This does not seem fixed, at least I and another user still have the problem: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329167/comments-on-proposed-topic-changes-behave-oddly-on-revision