# Comments on proposed topic changes behave oddly on revision

Tags: bug, comments, documentation, proposed-changes

You can comment on topic changes. But last night, I encountered something very strange. I was commenting on a change, and the person behind the change was revising the edit. But every time he did so, my comments disappeared.

So I'd post the comment again. But when I did, the *original* comment would suddenly appear, as well as my duplicate. Refreshing the page did not help.

And even now, the [change that I believe I was commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2B%2B/drafts/33937) on lacks all of the comments (that change may have been deleted and re-created).

Comment: Looks like I accidentally duplicated this… http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329188/old-comments-from-previous-draft-cant-decide-upon-their-existence … but for illustration: http://i.stack.imgur.com/evIVb.png