# Old comments from previous draft can't decide upon their existence

Tags: bug, comments, documentation, proposed-changes

On this change suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/42237

I've added a comment on an old revision of this. Now, he retracted the original revision and resubmitted (with changes? don't remember...).

Now, that comment usually isn't present on the new version, but when I add a comment (see the "`..............?`" comment I've added), the old comment magically re-appears there; and vanishes again after a reload.

[image: magical comment appearance??]

…

What is even the expected behavior here? But the way it currently is, it's broken in any case.

Comment: Nice freehand red annotations!

Comment: @JoshCaswell well, they're _obligatory_ on meta, no? But thanks for the dupe, couldn't find it before…